# Prove the equation if $b$ is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> When $b$ is prime and $a>0$ is any integer:
> $$(1/a)\pmod b \equiv a^{b-2}\pmod b$$

Can somebody explain me how this equation holds true in number theory.

Someone told me that it can be proven through Euler's theorem, but how?

Comment: Which Euler's Theorem are you thinking of?

Comment: what is $%$ in this context, remainder after division?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Fermat's little theorem: If $p$ is prime and $a$ is an integer not divisible by $p$, then
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p.$$
Since $a$ has an inverse mod $p$, we can divide both sides of the congruence by $a$ to get
$$a^{p-2}\equiv a^{-1}\pmod p.$$

*Remark 1*: This is your result, but with $b=p$. Also, I have written $a^{-1}$ instead of $1/a$.

*Remark 2*: You write that $a$ can be any integer, but you need to assume that $a$ is not divisible by $p$.

*Remark 3*: You refer to "Euler's theorem", but this is really Fermat's little theorem. Sometimes a generalization of this theorem is called the "Euler-Fermat theorem" or just "Euler's theorem", so that might be what was meant.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)